# WebBrowser control

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

How to use WebBrowser in windows mobile 6.5

Comment: your question is not complete, too short, or vague. you need to tell us what you want to do, what you have done, and where you have problems, so that we can help you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has  MSDN to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The following CodeProject article demonstrates how to build an RSS reader using the WebBrowser control on a Windows 7 phone:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/wp7rssreader.aspx